# how to checkin a place in facebook sdk 3 Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-4.2-jelly-bean, facebook-checkins

I want to check in a place using Facebook sdk 3.And it  should be post in wall as a check in .I have the place id .does any one have idea how to do it and any code >>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString("access_token", "YOUR ACCESS TOKEN");
data.putString("place", "your_place_id");  
data.putString("message","Your Text here");
JSONObject coordinates = new JSONObject();
coordinates.put("latitude", "LATITUDE");
coordinates.put("longitude", "LONGITUDE");
data.putString("coordinates",coordinates.toString());
data.putString("tags", "user_id");
String response = faceBook.request("me/checkins", data, "POST");
```

Comment: yes,thank it work,but faceBook.request("me/checkins", data, "POST"); is not in sdk 3 ,but we can use wall post method with this budle